# BIND9 server types

Tags: domain-name-system, configuration, bind

I was configuring DNS on my server using BIND9, everything seems to work, but I have a question regarding my config file.

I've ended up with this configuration in `/etc/bind/named.conf.local`

```
zone "example.com" {
  type master;
  file "/etc/bind/db.example.com";
  allow-transfer { 192.168.1.1; };
};
zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
  type master;
  notify no;
  file "/etc/bind/db.192";
  allow-transfer { 192.168.1.1; };
};
forwarders {
  10.253.22.140;
  10.253.22.141;
};
```

I've read about the different type of dns server, like primary master etc. The first two parts (zone and zone) corresponds to primary dns server configuration. First record for "classic" lookup, second one for reverse. The last part (forwarders) is configuration of cache-server and contains the ISP's IP of DNS server. So all names resolved thanks to this server will be cached.

Simple question: am I right? Does my description make sense? Or one server can be only either master or either cached?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single installation of Bind can handle all roles, primary, secundary, caching.
The fowarders line in the config means that when the server does not know the answer to your query (from cache, or own zone files) it will query one of the forwarders for you, instead of doing a zone lookup starting from "." (root).

By default, bind caches all DNS requests.

Comment: great, that's enough for me, thx